# How to render component from another js page reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, render

I'm new to reactjs. I have a multiple class in multiple page. My received error:

> ReferenceError: WelcomeView is not defined

Chat.js:

```
var Chat = React.createClass({

render: function() {
 return (
  <div>
    <WelcomeView />
    <MainView />
  </div>
);
}

});

ReactDOM.render(<Chat />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

WelcomeView and MainView are in another page.

WelcomeView.js:

```
var WelcomeView = React.createClass({

render: function() {
  ...
}

}

});
```

in index.html:

```
<script src="react/build/react.js"></script>
<script src="react/build/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>

<script src="script/WelcomeView.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="script/MainView.js" type="text/babel"></script>
<script src="script/Chat.js" type="text/babel"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reference to your WelcomeView and MainView components.

WelcomeView.js

```
window.WelcomeView = React.createClass({    
    render: function() {
        ...
    } 
});
```

Chat.js

```
var MainView = window.MainView;
var WelcomeView  = window.WelComeView;

var Chat = React.createClass({    
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <WelcomeView />
                <MainView />
            </div>
        );
});

ReactDOM.render(<Chat />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Edit: Kesh Shan is right. You aren't using a module bundler so import won't work. Attaching the classes to the window might do the trick.

Comment: ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: @Digipng If you are not using any module bundler like webpack or etc. You should assign you components to some javascript global object, because objects from .jsx are not put in global scope